# Cramer's type system which variables are vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume that $X$ is a vector space over $K$ and $y_i\in X$ ($i=1,...,n$) $a_{ij}\in K$ ( $i,j=1,...,n$).

Let's consider the system of linear equations:

$$
a_{11}x_1+a_{12}x_2+...+a_{1n}x_n=y_1  
$$
$$
....
$$
$$
a_{n1}x_1+a_{n2}x_2+...+a_{nn}x_n=y_n
$$
with vector variables $x_1,...,x_n\in X$ and deteminant $det[a_{ij}]\neq0$.

Motivated by a classical Cramer's theorem :
does this system has  solution and if this solution exists is it unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and yes. Choose a basis of $X$ and write each vector in your system as a linear combination of elements of the basis. Then your system will break down to one ordinary (i.e. involving scalar variables, not vector variables) linear system for each coordinate/element of the basis. Even if $\dim X = \infty$, your original system will have a unique solution since each $y_i$ will have non-zero coefficients only at finitely many coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's correct. All you need to show the system has a unique solution is $[a_{ij}]$ is an invertible matrix. You can derive a similar Cramer's formula if you use $y_1,\dots,y_n$ as a generating system and write $x_i$ as a linear combination of $y_j$'s. But that's really just to find the inverse of $[a_{ij}]$.